# How to synchronously execute FOR LOOP using $q promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, q, synchronous

I have an array of Facebook groupIDs that I want to check in synchronous order, and if one fails, to skip to the next. When they all finish executing, I want to send all the results to my server.

The below code explains the gist of what I want to accomplish (of course it does not work):

```
var groups = [1111,2222,3333];
var feed_collection = [];

// Unfortunately this for loop does not wait for the FB api calls to finish before looping to next
for(var x = 0; x < groups.length; x++){
   FB.api("/"+groups[x]+"/feed", function(response, err){
      feed_collection += response;
   });
}
// Send the feed_collection to server
feed_collection.sendToServer();
```

How can I get my for loop to wait? I know I can use `$q.all()`, however I am stuck on how to generate the promises and save them to a `promise_array`. This code is on the client-side and I am using AngularJS 1, but I am open to any approach. Mucho gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getGroupFeed(groupId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  FB.api('/' + groupId + '/feed', function (response, err) {
    if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
    return deferred.resolve(response);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

That is how you can quickly generate a promise in Angular. Now you can also create an array of promises:

```
var groupPromises = groups.map(function (groupId) {
  return getGroupFeed(groupId);
});
```

Or if you insist on a for loop:

```
var groupPromises = [];
for (var i = 0, len = groups.length; i < len; i++) {
  groupPromises.push(getGroupFeed(group[i]));
}
```

This array of promises can then be used in `$q.all`, which is only resolved once all promises in the array are resolved.

Comment: How would I get this to execute in a for loop? Is it as simple as wrapping the `getGroupFeed` function in a for loop?

Comment: Still this is not synchronous.

Comment: @KangzeHuang , you don't have to use for loop. This approach gives you what you're asking for promise_array and it is more readable and less error prone than for loop.

Comment: This will create an array of promises synchronously – the promises themself though are not synchronous, and they shouldn't be.

I added a for loop example to my answer.

Comment: Ahh I see, the `groups.map` achieves the same thing! Thanks very much @Phillip and @Avinash!  :)

Comment: Just one last question. What would happen if one of the `FB.api` calls failed? When I use `$q.all()` would it simply skip the failed call?

Comment: If just a single promise fails (rejects) then the promise returned by `$q.all` will also reject.

Comment: I see. Is this a hard-set feature of `$q.all()` or is there a way I can get error-skipping?

Comment: Well you can just `.resolve` errors in the `getGroupFeed` function I wrote instead of `.reject`ing them, and then do some manual error checking when going through the results from the `$q.all` promise.

Comment: Just FYI the API call will actually be executed when you call `getGroupFeed()` `$q.all()` doesn't execute anything here only consumes. Just thought i'd best mention.

Comment: Yeah, if it didn't execute the promises would forever be pending